# HttpClient.post is sucessful but not sending data to json

Tags: json, angular, angular-httpclient

I am trying to store data from my angular app into a JSON. The JSON is stored within the assets folder of my app and I have the app on a server.

I am using `HttpClient` to `POST` data to the JSON. It says it is successful but it does not actually send the data.

This is my .ts:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http'

export class OpscreenComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private httpService: HttpClient ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    var jsonpost = {
      "testing": [
        {
          "anothertest":"here",
          "anumber": 1
        }
      ]
    }
    var headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
    var options = { headers: headers }
    this.httpService.post("http://servername/angularApp/assets/testing.json", jsonpost, options)
    .subscribe(
      data=> {
        console.log("POST Request is Successful ", data )
      },
      error => {
        console.log("Error ", error)
      }
    )

  }

}
```

I get no error messages and the request is successful because it is logging `POST Request is Successful  null` in the console.

The json is blank to start and after the POST success it is still blank (hence the `null` in the console.)

Why is it not posting the data to the JSON?

I am using `httpClient` for `get` so I know it is imported correctly.

Comment: Try it with POSTMAN and confirm the actual response data

Comment: What does *but it does not actually send the data* mean? My guess is your server is not sending any data back, so not the angular code.

Comment: Your actual issue is that it doesn't return anything, not that it doesn't send anything.

Comment: The json is blank after the post request. If the JSON was not blank after the post request and it still returned `null`. Then yes, the issue would be that it is not returning anything.

Comment: *the issue would be that it is not returning anything* so what does that have to do with angular/javascript? Debug your server side code

Comment: Check your network tab to see what's actually sent and returned

Comment: @David It tells me that the Status is `200 OK`. It has the `Request Payload` as well, which is the `jsonpost`. But, it says `This request has no response data available`.

Comment: There you go, your API request does not return anything. So you should investigate why, probably in the backend if you are confident that the correct post payload is sent (and if you have no error in the console/network tab)

Answer (score 0):

```
this.httpService.request('POST', `${YourTestUri}`, { body: jsonpost, headers: headers }).pipe( switchMap( (response: any) => ... ) );
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score -2):

What you are trying to do is write files to disk, unfortunately, The `HttpClient` of Angular can't write files to disk. At least not with the classic implementation.

You probably prefer to add a server who can write to the disk, and your `HttpClient` will hit the server with the corresponding data.